# Not able to `install` or `update` nodejs in Ubuntu platform

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

In my terminal if I run the command as `nodejs -v`, I am getting a result as  `v0.10.25`. But I am not able to update in to new version. as well when i try to intiate a new version of `nodejs` using this command :

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash` I am getting an error as :

`## Confirming "n/a" is supported...

- curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x/dists/n/a/Release'

### Your distribution, identified as "n/a", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support

`

How to fix this? and what is wrong with my `VM` box? I am using `5.1.18`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three most popular ways to install Node is manually from sources, manually from binaries and using `nvm`. (You rarely want to install Node with the system package manager but it's also an option.)

I wrote a tutorial on installing Node from sources or from binaries on Linux. See:

- https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a

For example you can do something like this:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.7.0/node-v6.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-v6.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo chown -Rv root.root node-v6.7.0-linux-x64
sudo cp -Rvi node-v6.7.0-linux-x64/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/local
```

You didn't say wher you want it installed - see the tutorial for more options. Of course change the version to the one you want.

See also some answers on Stack Overflow that may be useful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723668/node-installed-but-node-cannot-be-found-in-ubuntu-vps/40724019#40724019
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180505/node-5-5-0-already-installed-but-node-v-fetches-with-v4-2-1-on-os-x-homebre/37181311#37181311
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312651/how-to-run-node-js-on-dedicated-server/41313267#41313267
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396941/npm-and-node-command-not-found-when-using-nvm/41397096#41397096

Comment: When I install using your command, it ask no of `overwrite` - how to `overwrite` all? after that still i am getting result as `dev@ubuntu14044:~$ nodejs -v v0.10.25`